# Couldn't resolve host 'cdk-builds.usersys.redhat.com'

Tags: vagrant, openshift, redhat, microservices, fabric8

While installing vagrant i'm getting following error....
I'm following https://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/cdk.html for installation.

```
pwd

/Users/apple/openshift-vagrant/cdk-v2

vagrant up

Bringing machine 'cdk' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> cdk: Box 'cdk_v2' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    cdk: Box Provider: virtualbox
    cdk: Box Version: >= 0
==> cdk: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> cdk: Adding box 'cdk_v2' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    cdk: Downloading: http://cdk-builds.usersys.redhat.com/builds/nightly/27-May-2016/rhel-7-cdk-vagrant-scratch-7.2.27052016-1.x86_64.vagrant-virtualbox.box
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't resolve host 'cdk-builds.usersys.redhat.com'
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Prerequisites](https://github.com/redhat-developer-tooling/openshift-vagrant#prerequisites) you need

> **Active VPN connection during the creation and provisioning of the VM**

If you're not connected to the internal Red Hat network, you will not be able to download the box

You should use another box / Vagrantfile

Answer (score 0):

We do not recommend using Vagrant anymore, but you should favor using minikube or minishift instead.

http://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/index.html